# clearing all usercontrol in the wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

How to clear all usercontrols in the wpf window. in runtime i added dynamic usercontrols in my wpf window, when i refresh, i want to clear all those and need to load again. so how i can clear all usercontrols in my page.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Window class itself has a single child which you can clear by setting the `Content` property to null.  If you added the controls to a Panel, such as a Grid or Canvas, then you can clear them by calling the Clear method on the Children property:

```
myCanvas.Children.Clear();
```